# How to search through a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray that I need to search for a string and return the key in the array where the string was found. So for example if I'm searching "ipod" and it's the 4th in the array, it would return 3 or whatever position the string is in. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Index of an Object from NSArray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398141/getting-index-of-an-object-from-nsarray)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
return [theArray indexOfObject:@"ipod"];
```

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:.

Note that NSMutableArray inherits from NSArray, so any NSArray methods can be used on NSMutableArray too.

Comment: Would you know how to do it with objects within the array? For example I'm using the XMLParser and would want to know where the word iPod is located in a sub object.

Answer (score 2):

Again from the documentation:
[Index of Object Passing test](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObjectPassingTest%3a)

You'll have to write a [code block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) that tests for the substring in each object: [NSString rangeOfString: options:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3aoptions%3a)

Then you'll get the index of the object with the substring. You'll need to run the string search again for your result, but that should get you what you are after.