# Getting Index of an Object from NSArray?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray

i am trying to get index of an array through **indexOfObject** method as follows but when i try to log the value to test the index i get a garbage value.. for testing purposes i am having an array with values `{57,56,58..}` to get an index of lets say `56`,

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:56];
NSInteger Aindex = [myArray indexOfObject:num];
NSLog(@" %d",Aindex);
```

the value i get is something like `2323421`. what am i possibly doing wrong??

Comment: Are you actually inserting it into the array?

Comment: **What kind of data type value your myArray contains**

Comment: i was adding a NSString value to array and comparing the array object with a NSNumber.. didnt thought it would be a problem but eventually had to compare the object with a string value to get it right..

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The index returned by `indexOfObject` will be the first index for an occurence of your object. Equality is tested using `isEqual` method.
The garbage value you get is probably equal to `NSNotFound`.
Try testing `anIndex` against it. The number you are looking for isn't probably in your array :

```
NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:56];
NSInteger anIndex=[myArray indexOfObject:num];
if(NSNotFound == anIndex) {
    NSLog(@"not found");
}
```

or log the content of the array to be sure :

```
NSLog(@"%@", myArray);
```

Comment: i was adding a NSString value to array and comparing the array object with a NSNumber.. didnt thought it would be a problem but eventually had to compare the object with a string value to get it right..

Comment: What if i have same object multiple time?

Answer (score 40):

Folks,

When an object is not found in the array the indexOfObject method does NOT return a 'garbage' value. Many systems return an index of -1 if the item is not found.

However, on IOS - because the indexOfObject returns an UNSIGNED int (aka NSUInteger) the returned index must be greater than or equal to zero. Since 'zero' is a valid index there is no way to indicate to the caller that the object was not found -- except by returning an agreed upon constant value that we all can test upon. This constant agreed upon value is called NSNotFound.

The method:

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject;
```

will return NSNotFound if the object was not in the array. NSNotFound is a very large POSITIVE integer (usually 1 minus the maximum int on the platform).

Comment: @joe If you CMD+click NSNotFound, you'll see that it is defined as `enum {NSNotFound = NSIntegerMax};`. I know both NSIntegerMax and NSUIntegerMax are both positive, but wouldn't it have been more sensible to use NS**U**IntegerMax since it used in functions that return NSUInteger? Also, what if I'm searching for an object that is placed at index NSIntegerMax of the array? Wouldn't I be tricked into thinking that the object is NSNotFound?

Answer (score 6):

```
NSNumber *num1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:56];
    NSNumber *num2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:57];
    NSNumber *num3 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:58];
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:num1,num2,num3,nil];
    NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:58];

    NSInteger Aindex=[myArray indexOfObject:num];

    NSLog(@" %d",Aindex);
```

Its giving the correct output, may be u have done something wrong with storing objects in ur array.

Answer (score 5):

**Try this:**

NSArray's `indexOfObject:` method. Such as the following:

```
NSUInteger fooIndex = [someArray indexOfObject: someObject];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Swift and optionals make sure they are unwrapped.  You cannot search the index of objects that are optionals.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked. Its working fine for me. Check if your array has the particular number. It will return such garbage values if element is not present.

Answer (score 0):

indexOfObject methord will get the index of the corresponding string in that array if the string is like @"Test" and you find like @"TEST" Now this will retun an index like a long number