# how to find the Array index value in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Index of an Object from NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398141/getting-index-of-an-object-from-nsarray)

I have one Array and one string.  Array name is "Array1", String name is "String", Now i have this below Values in "Array1".

```
"array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e", nil];"
```

My String value is **"A"**

Now i want to compare these string and array. And i want to display the Array index value.

How can i do this. Please somebody help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {
  id myArrayElement = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
...do something useful with myArrayElement
 }`
```

You can Iterate NSMutableArray and to find the location of particular Object use

```
 int indexValue = [myArray indexOfObject:yourString];
```

Comment: if i get Numbers means what can i do? (e.x): @"1",@"2", like in array1, and string values is @"1".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. THen if i get the NUmbers means what can i do? for e.x "array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];" And another array values @"1". how can i compare this. Please help me to solve this isse.

Comment: not too much clear i think as you can compare NSString and you can convert it into int.

Comment: This is perfectly worked fine in my code

Answer (score 15):

i'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but maybe:

```
int index = [array1 indexOfObject:String];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. THen if i get the NUmbers means what can i do? for e.x "array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];" And another array values @"1". how can i compare this. Please help me to solve this isse.

Comment: sorry, i don't get what exactly you mean. What do you want to compare? strings, arrays or indexes?

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
if([array1 containsObject: yourString])
{
   int index = [array1 indexOfObject:yourString];
}
```

Comment: two querys? I suggest to use NSNotFound on the result for performance reasons!

Comment: @JonathanCichon But he wants to compare the string with array elements..

Comment: but your `containsObject` is completly unnecessary, as `indexOfObject` does all you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
NSString *String=@"A";
NSInteger index = [array1 indexOfObject:String];
```

**NOTE : Never use variable name with capital `String`, it should be `string`.**

Answer (score 1):

Checking

```
int index = [yourArray indexOfObject:yourObject];
```

is correct for `NSString` objects and some other types of objects.

When you have implemented a class on your own and you want to get the index of an object within an array you have to implement the method

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject
```