# iOS how do I fix an array returning an index for an object that can't be found

Tags: ios, arrays, ios7, nsarray

My array is returning an incorrect number for an index of an object that I am looking for. My array.count tells me there are 248 objects in the array, but the index that is returned is 2147483647. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398141/getting-index-of-an-object-from-nsarray) that is similar to mine issue. I used the equality testing that was proposed in this post, but fell short of figuring out why this was happening and how to fix it.

Here is my code: (Edited with solution)

```
-(void)getChamberPrimaryCategories
{
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    chamberCategoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    _databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                     initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                      @"the_app.db"]];

    NSLog(@"%@",_databasePath);

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_the_app_database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database");
        }
    }

    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_the_app_database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *querySQL;

        querySQL = @"SELECT DISTINCT CHAMBER_PRIMARY_CATEGORY FROM PLACES WHERE CHAMBER_PRIMARY_CATEGORY IS NOT '' AND CHAMBER_PRIMARY_CATEGORY IS NOT NULL ORDER BY CHAMBER_PRIMARY_CATEGORY ASC";


        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_the_app_database,
                               query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Query the database now.");
            //            if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_ROW) {
            //                NSLog(@"Not okay");
            //            }
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSLog(@"Getting Information:");

                placesChamber *chamberCategoryObject = [[placesChamber alloc]init];

                NSString *placesPrimaryChamberCategory = [[NSString alloc]
                                                          initWithUTF8String:
                                                          (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(
                                                                                             statement, 0)];
                chamberCategoryObject.primary_category = placesPrimaryChamberCategory;

                NSLog(@"%@",placesPrimaryChamberCategory);

                [chamberCategoryArray addObject:chamberCategoryObject];
            }//end while

        }//end if
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"There is nothing in this database!");
            NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(_the_kearney_app_database));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_the_kearney_app_database);

        [chamberCategoryTableView reloadData];

        NSLog(@"content offset: %f",chamberCategoryTableView.contentOffset.y);
        if (chamberCategoryTableView.contentOffset.y == 0)
        {

            placesChamber *searchChamber = [[placesChamber alloc] init];
            searchChamber.primary_category = @"Women's Clothing";
            NSUInteger index = [chamberCategoryArray indexOfObject:searchChamber];
            if (index == NSNotFound) {
                // no such chamber category
                NSLog(@"no such thing found");
            } else {
                // Found it at index
                NSLog(@"found it!");
            }


        }//end if

    }//end if

}
```

[image: Debugger Showing Object in Array]

Here is my placesChamber.m: (Needed for solution)

```
#import "placesChamber.h"

@implementation placesChamber

@synthesize ID;
@synthesize name;
@synthesize type;
@synthesize category;
@synthesize latitude;
@synthesize longitude;
@synthesize primary_category;
@synthesize secondary_category;

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    if ( self == object ) {
        return YES;
    }

    if ( ![object isKindOfClass:[placesChamber class]] ) {
        return NO;
    }

    if ( ![primary_category isEqualToString:[object primary_category]] ) {
        return  NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: That's the value for `NSNotFound`. That means your object isn't in the array.

Comment: just check if the index is `!=NSNotFound` then make what you want with it , else it is not found in your array.

Comment: BTW - your array contains instances of `placesChamber` objects but you are looking for an `NSNumber` object and an `NSString` literal. That will never work.

Comment: @rmaddy I understand that it is the value for NSNotFound, but why am I getting it? I changed the issue with the NSNumber back to what it is supposed to be. By the way thanks for looking at my problem.

Comment: BTW, the debugger variable view is quite unreliable.  The only way to be sure of what a value is is to use NSLog or, in the console, use `po`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, you have populated your `chamberCategoryArray` with instances of `placesChamber` objects.

But you then attempt to find the index of one of these objects not by passing in a `placesChamber` object but by passing in an `NSString` literal. That simply won't work.

You need to do something like this:

```
placesChamber *searchChamber = [[placesChamber alloc] init];
searchChamber.primary_category = @"Women's Clothing";
NSUInteger index = [chamberCategoryArray indexOfObject:searchChamber];
if (index == NSNotFound) {
    // no such chamber category
} else {
    // Found it at index
}
```

This code assumes you have implemented the `isEqual:` method on your `placesChamber` class that compares the `primary_category` property.

Side notes: It is standard convention that classnames begin with uppercase letters while method names and variables begin with lowercase. All should use camel case.

Given this your class should be `PlacesChamber` and the property should be `primaryCategory`.

Comment: I added this: 
`placesChamber *searchChamber = [[placesChamber alloc] init];
searchChamber.primary_category = @"Women's Clothing";
NSUInteger index = [chamberCategoryArray indexOfObject:searchChamber];
if (index == NSNotFound) {
    // no such chamber category
    NSLog(@"no such thing found");
} else {
    // Found it at index
    NSLog(@"found it!");
}`

I still returned NSNotFound.

Comment: Update your question with the implementation of the `isEqual:` method on your `placesChamber` class.

Comment: Updated My question. Hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Given that implementation of your `isEqual:` method it should work. To be safe, add the `hash` method: `- (NSUInteger)hash { return [self.primary_category hash]; }`.

Comment: Updated my question and I am still getting no such thing found.

Comment: I just noticed a mistake you made in the update. You are calling `indexOfObject:searchChamber.primary_category`. It needs to be `indexOfObject:searchChamber` just like in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I will update that. I tried it both ways and neither worked. But I changed it back and it worked this time. So I think it was the `isEqual` method implementation, because I did not have that in there before. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Without the `isEqual:` method it will only find an object with the same address.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you have used `indexOfObject:` in the following 3 lines of code:

```
//1.
NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[chamberCategoryArray indexOfObject:[defaults objectForKey:@"chamber filter category"]] inSection:0];

//2.
NSLog(@"index number: %lu",(unsigned long)[chamberCategoryArray indexOfObject:@"Women's Clothing"]);

//3.
if(NSNotFound == [chamberCategoryArray indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]]) {
    NSLog(@"not found");
}
```

And you are populating your `chamberCategoryArray` in the following line which is populating the array with an object of type `placesChamber`:

```
[chamberCategoryArray addObject:chamberCategoryObject];
```

Now if you pass an `indexOfObject:` message to an `NSArray` (or its subclass), it iterates through the array sending each object of the array an `isEqual:` message for equality and if one found, it returns the index, otherwise returns `NSNotFound` (as you are getting). And this equality comparison is based on the calculated hash code for each contained object, that is, if one object in the array has the same hash code (calculated internally) as the object it is being compared to, those are treated as equal.

In your example code:

- In 1. you are checking the hash codes of the objects of the array
  with the hash code of `[defaults objectForKey:@"chamber filter
  category"]` and I'm not sure what `defaults` made of.
- In 2. you are checking the elements against a `NSString`. But the
  objects of the array are of type `placesChamber` and hash codes for
  two different types never match and you would always get `NSNotFound`
  as a result.
- In 3. you are doing the same error, this time with a `NSNumber`
  instead of a `NSString`. So the above logic holds here also.

So it's very obvious you would get `NSNotFound` (2147483647) as a occasional result.

I believe you are trying to return the index of an object from the array(which is actually a `placesChamber` by type) that has a property matching your test criteria. For that purpose you might use `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` method that takes a block to write your comparison logic. Inside the block, you can write your own customized logic of matching an array item with your search criteria and the object index would be returned accordingly.

### Update

This what you are actually looking for at the first place:

```
NSString* criteria = @"Women's Clothing";
int index = [chamberCategoryArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        placesChamber* item = obj;
        *stop = [item.primary_category isEqualToString:criteria];
        return *stop;
 }];
```

Here I have demonstrated how to obtain the index based on `primary_category` property of `placesChamber` objects. The same method holds for other properties as well.

Comment: You are incorrect about how `indexOfObject:` works. You are correct when you say that `isEqual:` is called for each object. But that's all that is done. The hash has no play in this at all. The two objects are considered equal if the `isEqual:` method returns `YES`. That's it. So it all depends on the proper implementation of the `isEqual:` method for the objects involved. Since the OP has an array with one type of objects and is looking for a different kind of object, `isEqual:` will never return `YES`.

Comment: @rmaddy `isEqual:` is strictly related to `hash` if not overridden. Actually, if not overridden, the default implementation of `isEqual:` compares the hash codes of the two objects for equality, returned by `hash` method, by themselves. For details please go through [the link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:)

Comment: Yes, `isEqual:` and `hash` should always be written as a pair so they work together properly. And yes, the default of both is basically the object address. None of that is relevant. Your answer keeps stressing that the hash is checked. It is not. The `isEqual:` method is called. That's it. If it so happens that the default implementation of `isEqual:` calls `hash`, that is an irrelevant secondary point. In this case, the user has (or needs to) override `isEqual:` to compare the object's properties as needed. When done, `hash` will have no play at all in this code.

Comment: @rmaddy Again I would beg to differ.:( `hash` has nothing to do with object's address rather it depends on the content and internal hashing algo. To satisfy, please create two `NSString`, `str1` and `str2` and set the same value like `@"Hello"` to both of them. Now if you compare them with `isEqual:`, you would find that it returns `YES` though the objects have different address. As for my answer is concerned, I have just tried to clarify that how `isEqual` behaves internally. But you are somewhat correct that I might have been over-explanative. Thanks :)

Comment: As I said, the default (in `NSObject`) uses the object address. `NSString` overrides both `hash` and `isEqual:` to work as expected. No address is used for `NSString`. Your example with `NSString` isn't relevant. A better example would be to create two `NSObject` instances.

Comment: Sorry! I'v misinterpreted you. Actually you are right for `NSObject`