# adding search to NSMutable Array with DetailView

Tags: uitableview, ios6, uisearchbar

i have project that I'm  working on and i need to add search to my `uitableview`. i have been looking at lots of codes but mostly they are not what i am looking for and i can't modify them . can someone please help me with adding search to my `tableview`. also i want to push the `detailview` from `searcharray`. thank you in advance.

here is the .h `uitableview`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Reds : UITableViewController {
NSMutableArray *dummyArray;
}
- (void) setupData;

@end
```

here is .m `uitableview`

```
#import "Reds.h"
#import "RedsDetail.h"

@interface Reds ()

@end

@implementation Reds

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self setupData];
}

- (void) setupData {
dummyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[dummyArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"dummy 1", @"name" , @"image1.JPG", @"image" , @"dummy 1 description textview", @"description", nil]];
[dummyArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"dummy 2", @"name" , @"image1.JPG", @"image" , @"dummy 2 description textview", @"description", nil]];
[dummyArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"dummy 3", @"name" , @"image1.JPG", @"image" , @"dummy 3 description textview", @"description", nil]];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [dummyArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = [[dummyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DummyDetail"]){
    RedsDetail *dummyDetail = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    dummyDetail.dummyImageString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[dummyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]];
    dummyDetail.dummyTextString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[dummyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description"]];
    dummyDetail.title = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[dummyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];
}
}

@end
```

here is the .h `detailview`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RedsDetail : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIImageView *dummyImage;
IBOutlet UITextView *dummyText;
NSString *dummyImageString;
NSString *dummyTextString;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dummyImageString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dummyTextString;
@end
```

and finally the .m `detailview`

```
#import "RedsDetail.h"

@interface RedsDetail ()

@end

@implementation RedsDetail
@synthesize dummyImageString, dummyTextString;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

dummyImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:dummyImageString];
dummyText.text = dummyTextString;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

i know it might be a easy answer for most of you guys out there but i can't figure it out and i need help. i truly appreciate the time you guys spending in helping me. also i am using xcode 4.5 ios 6 storyboard if that makes a difference in your answers.

adrian

Comment: I think this post will lead you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609958/how-to-search-through-a-nsmutablearray

Comment: thanks david, but i was looking for code snippet help. i have been through the documentation but i am having a hard time doing this without changing my class structure. i am trying to avoid that. but if i can't get any help i may have to.:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the search, create a searchArray and a searchText, also you need a textfield that invokes the didChange method.

Use this to link the textfield to the didChange method:

```
[self.searchTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Then in the didChange update the searchText and call the updateSearchArray.

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)textField
{
    searchTextString = textField.text;
    [self updateSearchArray];
}
```

In the updateSearchArray you compare go through the original array (dummyArray) and if the name is included in the search then add it to the searchArray.

```
-(void)updateSearchArray
{
    if (searchTextString.length != 0) {
        searchArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for ( NSDictionary* item in dummyArray ) {
            if ([[[item objectForKey:@"name"] lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchTextString lowercaseString]].location != NSNotFound) {
                [searchArray addObject:item];
            }
        }
    } else {
        searchArray = dummyArray;
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

---

Use the searchArray in the tableview methods where you now use the dummyArray.

Updated tableview methods

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [searchArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    return cell;
}
```

Also, you need to call a reloadData after adding all the data to the array. And added the updateSearchArray method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupData];
    [self updateSearchArray];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

---

---

**To make it easier to implement this I have made a sample project. You can download it here:** http://www.rolandkeesom.com/SearchExample.zip

---

---

Comment: thanks for your response. can you plug in the code into my sample data provided and show me how its done, because i can't seem to do it the right way. i am so frustrated. this should be seriously simple and i can't do it. that's why i offered a bounty. i am about to give up on this set of codes. :(

Comment: i tried your updated code and i get couple of warnings and an error. i edited my post with the code you provided. can you please check it out.

Comment: Change searchText into searchTextString. I have updated the code in my post. Also in your .h file add NSString *searchTextString;

Comment: sorry roland it does not work. i will leave this open to hopefully get someone to plug in the code into what i have in my post so i can see where i am going wrong. but thanks for your time and help. i will upvote your answer just to say thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I will try later to build it with your code and see if I can make it work.

Comment: I have edited my post and added a sample project. To make it a little more readable I changed some of the file names

Comment: it works thank you, thank you, thank you. it is not the prettiest with a text field rather than search bar but it does the job and i can always play around in ib. i am truly grateful for your help. i just mmarked your answer as the correct one and thank you again.